# Show/Hide CRM controls malfunctioning

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I am setting the section properties of CRM form to have label & control in separate rows like below:

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

By default the form control will be visible=false. When I try the below snippets only label is showing up but not the textbox. If I use side by side setting, its working as expected.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("myattribute").setVisible(true);
```

or

```
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get('myattribute').setVisible(true);
```

Can I achieve this by some other supported means?

**Update:**
Ours is CRM 2015 on-premise. Not update 1.

I have tested the same behavior in Dynamics 365 CRM trial. Legacy form behaves the same way, but Turbo form is having the fix.

> [image]

Comment: Have you already tried different browsers to see if it's a browser-specific issue ?

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried in chrome, firefox, IE - same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be Product bug till date, even in latest version with legacy form.

For now as a workaround, we are keeping the controls in separate section to meet our need.

Am open to any other supported solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the following options and check if the issue persists ?

**1. Turn off legacy form rendering.**

[image: System Settings]
   [image]

**2. If you can use the Business Rules, to Show/Hide field and see if it works ?**

**3. You can use un-supported customization, to hide the textbox.**

```
     var curElement = document.getElementById(controlname + "_d");
     if (curElement != null)
          curElement.style.display = '';
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestions.
1. Forgot to mention, we are in 2015 onpremise (without Update 1). So no turbo forms. 
2. Same behavior with Business rule also. (BPF ?)
3. We want to be in supported zone

Comment: So keeping it in separate section with side by side option. Am planning to try in online trial with latest version. will update here.

Comment: Its also reproducing in latest CRM with legacy form. Anyway turbo engine is working fine.